Garage door will not open unless I hold button
I have to hold the remote control button to open the door, but it stops halfway up and when closing I have to keep pressing the button be cause it constantly stops. The sensors are clean and working correctly, while the cables on each end have good tension and the wheels roll freely. When I first experienced the issue I heard a loud pop as the door was opening and it hadn't worked right since...also the tracks are not bent.

Same issue as what? Please revise to tell us something about your hardware. A loud pop sounds like a circuit board failure.

With some door operator models, holding the button overrides safety sensors (the optical sensor, at least -- maybe the force sensors in the motor, too?). Have you looked at the springs? To help break the problem down, try disconnecting the operator from the door and ensure that the door operates well manually. If all is well mechanically you should be able to lift the door fully open with minimal exertion and re-close it with neither large effort nor loss of control.

It could also be a tension spring that's broken that's causing the door to not be balanced any more.  Does the door move easily in both directions if you disconnect the opener from the door?

Check the alignment of your sensor(s).  This happens to me occasionally and adjusting the sensors fixes the problem.
